# How do I create a a series of plots that demonstrate a change in variable over time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that is partitioned into 5 data intervals per simulation. I can easily plot each time interval using facet_grid(plotstamp~sim). Here is the data set and the output of the data set in ggplot.

```
data_long_sort<-structure(list(x = c(178.378914193811, 213.705280026717, 186.083745189027, 
72.0068974854884, 198.395174384572, 217.335582095298, 227.299417998954, 
162.728792513482, 385.415216072379, 99.2216438319074, 184.625419710364, 
167.991512569555, 179.750719472509, 162.995601345339, 115.376821296744, 
195.887280591859, 172.244056969666, 199.017518438611, 124.713261755517, 
224.174527941845, 160.026628270757, 266.827637563176, 164.764758640094, 
266.598008417104, 326.659221196217, 142.088402054167, 318.784585166027, 
348.072622258525, 205.452440049243, 371.235080473456, 263.467623706752, 
152.24302177943, 144.180944398972, 138.431754855541, 128.229196332292, 
212.577860989416, 139.860248290708, 261.018747123905, 245.10058253194, 
390.472789678232, 376.892923338888, 191.056848740513, 306.151555527134, 
408.860973862092, 381.666660983801, 264.75929530532, 188.112714005031, 
327.178442849702, 283.424161243508, 233.533361158228, 410.758925732075, 
360.089042064036, 196.410647057472, 95.4429123421252, 308.707275230342, 
126.886327541668, 367.22866130099, 234.132609026991, 181.491172373852, 
135.407577894867, 409.443703682194, 100.637419544717, 300.847848612684, 
52.5407631692288, 200.454665045588, 288.914239826336, 175.640920817946, 
401.287291508671, 205.157491391497, 142.332710053298, 416.928030545271, 
204.506900319576, 96.020244439213, 333.036553562921, 230.708814136027, 
169.641831480745, 115.842502835644, 334.109803321851, 368.765964419062, 
338.183243559796, 287.136665059345, 377.364242354898, 372.479801221051, 
376.561166350223, 345.609474067374, 286.575219949748, 214.980151686787, 
382.601841760389, 390.035122936582, 229.36320295928, 286.905053852344, 
99.2564352457302, 428.023373053956, 356.256436921878, 358.247529794377, 
332.075216412662, 304.387507793203, 296.540876792513, 276.354319107496, 
421.170471092586, 204.506900319576, 135.407577894867, 333.036553562921, 
408.860973862092, 124.713261755517, 327.178442849702, 345.609474067374, 
286.575219949748, 164.764758640094, 99.2216438319074, 276.354319107496, 
356.256436921878, 138.431754855541, 212.577860989416, 139.860248290708, 
390.472789678232, 179.750719472509, 162.728792513482, 287.136665059345, 
377.364242354898, 376.561166350223, 188.112714005031, 308.707275230342, 
126.886327541668, 266.827637563176, 142.088402054167, 390.035122936582, 
234.132609026991, 181.491172373852, 286.905053852344, 409.443703682194, 
100.637419544717, 300.847848612684, 318.784585166027, 200.454665045588, 
371.235080473456, 175.640920817946, 263.467623706752, 144.180944398972, 
169.641831480745, 338.183243559796, 376.892923338888, 191.056848740513, 
306.151555527134, 162.995601345339, 115.376821296744, 372.479801221051, 
195.887280591859, 264.75929530532, 172.244056969666, 296.540876792513, 
283.424161243508, 233.533361158228, 410.758925732075, 385.415216072379, 
196.410647057472, 95.4429123421252, 224.174527941845, 160.026628270757, 
72.0068974854884, 367.22866130099, 214.980151686787, 326.659221196217, 
382.601841760389, 229.36320295928, 288.914239826336, 205.157491391497, 
358.247529794377, 142.332710053298, 416.928030545271, 96.020244439213, 
304.387507793203, 230.708814136027, 115.842502835644, 128.229196332292, 
334.109803321851, 261.018747123905, 245.10058253194, 381.666660983801, 
199.017518438611, 360.089042064036, 428.023373053956, 348.072622258525, 
52.5407631692288, 205.452440049243, 198.395174384572, 401.287291508671, 
421.170471092586, 368.765964419062, 266.598008417104, 99.2564352457302, 
184.625419710364, 332.075216412662, 227.299417998954, 167.991512569555, 
213.705280026717, 178.378914193811, 152.24302177943, 217.335582095298, 
186.083745189027, 286.575219949748, 287.136665059345, 162.995601345339, 
296.540876792513, 276.354319107496, 304.387507793203, 333.036553562921, 
139.860248290708, 338.183243559796, 191.056848740513, 372.479801221051, 
264.75929530532, 327.178442849702, 229.36320295928, 286.905053852344, 
318.784585166027, 356.256436921878, 371.235080473456, 205.157491391497, 
358.247529794377, 142.332710053298, 261.018747123905, 245.10058253194, 
213.705280026717, 162.728792513482, 306.151555527134, 115.376821296744, 
377.364242354898, 408.860973862092, 195.887280591859, 381.666660983801, 
172.244056969666, 199.017518438611, 376.561166350223, 283.424161243508, 
233.533361158228, 360.089042064036, 196.410647057472, 95.4429123421252, 
345.609474067374, 308.707275230342, 160.026628270757, 367.22866130099, 
214.980151686787, 266.827637563176, 326.659221196217, 99.2216438319074, 
234.132609026991, 300.847848612684, 205.452440049243, 288.914239826336, 
263.467623706752, 144.180944398972, 416.928030545271, 169.641831480745, 
115.842502835644, 128.229196332292, 212.577860989416, 390.472789678232, 
376.892923338888, 179.750719472509, 188.112714005031, 124.713261755517, 
410.758925732075, 385.415216072379, 126.886327541668, 224.174527941845, 
72.0068974854884, 164.764758640094, 266.598008417104, 382.601841760389, 
142.088402054167, 390.035122936582, 181.491172373852, 135.407577894867, 
186.083745189027, 409.443703682194, 100.637419544717, 52.5407631692288, 
200.454665045588, 198.395174384572, 175.640920817946, 401.287291508671, 
217.335582095298, 332.075216412662, 138.431754855541, 96.020244439213, 
227.299417998954, 230.708814136027, 421.170471092586, 368.765964419062, 
167.991512569555, 99.2564352457302, 428.023373053956, 348.072622258525, 
184.625419710364, 204.506900319576, 178.378914193811, 334.109803321851, 
152.24302177943), y = c(72.3204552094791, 74.3340707245495, 81.3822241902731, 
358.12389998779, 150.721210282615, 54.9615315726734, 166.29213717224, 
328.418289080097, 206.881055620491, 439.482686287838, 166.727168080607, 
140.885987167398, 432.490061388379, 272.360433136786, 267.180381253212, 
330.770157321963, 344.410114861907, 324.223258588091, 448.305817286382, 
207.768948739363, 328.525881208647, 338.156420027474, 437.270045123144, 
166.430472425513, 317.060781801978, 440.220926385163, 290.747929038793, 
130.766407304654, 238.735762126117, 417.611712002266, 276.986603076743, 
114.540743168275, 433.329181324874, 462.628711536893, 339.509499561221, 
428.486189816085, 285.31743251511, 182.759925191817, 225.774048113164, 
371.517559851727, 304.672325209878, 263.878795834227, 299.866380762876, 
349.292764022541, 239.640170859808, 375.38327831299, 458.787708920491, 
356.657651099412, 301.376107777568, 217.485983004984, 447.074837000406, 
284.822683291858, 264.796281526645, 306.772306363867, 474.968211379616, 
407.979175035839, 259.756517752321, 341.560167630845, 466.140335260616, 
455.907769292915, 308.215585573261, 369.149428631289, 280.954362752667, 
291.469894286388, 403.857505064325, 268.547062433325, 368.684521993109, 
152.281028838043, 297.57198952587, 293.431457548692, 243.001891755255, 
494.608372616602, 343.826913864024, 398.793989125437, 218.544518831613, 
426.797016927976, 304.979257891182, 225.515282351772, 130.749552687306, 
443.074152825454, 405.942589880579, 440.475437805682, 449.392721626404, 
452.244050987379, 430.698777426512, 390.679275063817, 398.481248180829, 
270.940031045178, 303.724659104445, 349.074831816595, 443.411054982894, 
183.736689376843, 172.373204776896, 388.893026963794, 268.875594986492, 
150.935409546769, 453.319120283952, 419.156747641019, 418.906635864262, 
276.822318795003, 494.608372616602, 455.907769292915, 398.793989125437, 
349.292764022541, 448.305817286382, 356.657651099412, 430.698777426512, 
390.679275063817, 437.270045123144, 439.482686287838, 418.906635864262, 
388.893026963794, 462.628711536893, 428.486189816085, 285.31743251511, 
371.517559851727, 432.490061388379, 328.418289080097, 405.942589880579, 
440.475437805682, 452.244050987379, 458.787708920491, 474.968211379616, 
407.979175035839, 338.156420027474, 440.220926385163, 303.724659104445, 
341.560167630845, 466.140335260616, 443.411054982894, 308.215585573261, 
369.149428631289, 280.954362752667, 290.747929038793, 403.857505064325, 
417.611712002266, 368.684521993109, 276.986603076743, 433.329181324874, 
426.797016927976, 443.074152825454, 304.672325209878, 263.878795834227, 
299.866380762876, 272.360433136786, 267.180381253212, 449.392721626404, 
330.770157321963, 375.38327831299, 344.410114861907, 419.156747641019, 
301.376107777568, 217.485983004984, 447.074837000406, 206.881055620491, 
264.796281526645, 306.772306363867, 207.768948739363, 328.525881208647, 
358.12389998779, 259.756517752321, 398.481248180829, 317.060781801978, 
270.940031045178, 349.074831816595, 268.547062433325, 297.57198952587, 
268.875594986492, 293.431457548692, 243.001891755255, 343.826913864024, 
453.319120283952, 218.544518831613, 304.979257891182, 339.509499561221, 
225.515282351772, 182.759925191817, 225.774048113164, 239.640170859808, 
324.223258588091, 284.822683291858, 172.373204776896, 130.766407304654, 
291.469894286388, 238.735762126117, 150.721210282615, 152.281028838043, 
276.822318795003, 130.749552687306, 166.430472425513, 183.736689376843, 
166.727168080607, 150.935409546769, 166.29213717224, 140.885987167398, 
74.3340707245495, 72.3204552094791, 114.540743168275, 54.9615315726734, 
81.3822241902731, 390.679275063817, 405.942589880579, 272.360433136786, 
419.156747641019, 418.906635864262, 453.319120283952, 398.793989125437, 
285.31743251511, 443.074152825454, 263.878795834227, 449.392721626404, 
375.38327831299, 356.657651099412, 349.074831816595, 443.411054982894, 
290.747929038793, 388.893026963794, 417.611712002266, 297.57198952587, 
268.875594986492, 293.431457548692, 182.759925191817, 225.774048113164, 
74.3340707245495, 328.418289080097, 299.866380762876, 267.180381253212, 
440.475437805682, 349.292764022541, 330.770157321963, 239.640170859808, 
344.410114861907, 324.223258588091, 452.244050987379, 301.376107777568, 
217.485983004984, 284.822683291858, 264.796281526645, 306.772306363867, 
430.698777426512, 474.968211379616, 328.525881208647, 259.756517752321, 
398.481248180829, 338.156420027474, 317.060781801978, 439.482686287838, 
341.560167630845, 280.954362752667, 238.735762126117, 268.547062433325, 
276.986603076743, 433.329181324874, 243.001891755255, 426.797016927976, 
304.979257891182, 339.509499561221, 428.486189816085, 371.517559851727, 
304.672325209878, 432.490061388379, 458.787708920491, 448.305817286382, 
447.074837000406, 206.881055620491, 407.979175035839, 207.768948739363, 
358.12389998779, 437.270045123144, 166.430472425513, 270.940031045178, 
440.220926385163, 303.724659104445, 466.140335260616, 455.907769292915, 
81.3822241902731, 308.215585573261, 369.149428631289, 291.469894286388, 
403.857505064325, 150.721210282615, 368.684521993109, 152.281028838043, 
54.9615315726734, 150.935409546769, 462.628711536893, 343.826913864024, 
166.29213717224, 218.544518831613, 276.822318795003, 130.749552687306, 
140.885987167398, 183.736689376843, 172.373204776896, 130.766407304654, 
166.727168080607, 494.608372616602, 72.3204552094791, 225.515282351772, 
114.540743168275), id = c(92L, 7L, 60L, 43L, 73L, 84L, 91L, 11L, 
33L, 51L, 78L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 41L, 42L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 52L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 72L, 77L, 81L, 82L, 88L, 
97L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 44L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 
63L, 64L, 68L, 70L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 79L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 89L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 99L, 100L, 8L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 25L, 37L, 40L, 45L, 
50L, 53L, 54L, 58L, 59L, 66L, 71L, 80L, 87L, 90L, 27L, 62L, 98L, 
86L, 57L, 93L, 18L, 28L, 29L, 37L, 40L, 47L, 51L, 62L, 71L, 88L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 17L, 25L, 26L, 38L, 39L, 46L, 52L, 
53L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 70L, 72L, 75L, 77L, 82L, 
95L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 49L, 50L, 54L, 
74L, 79L, 80L, 83L, 85L, 89L, 90L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 3L, 4L, 
21L, 24L, 34L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 73L, 76L, 98L, 100L, 48L, 
59L, 78L, 87L, 91L, 5L, 7L, 92L, 81L, 84L, 60L, 40L, 13L, 15L, 
27L, 62L, 90L, 93L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 19L, 22L, 29L, 54L, 58L, 65L, 
71L, 72L, 79L, 80L, 83L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 42L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 49L, 51L, 55L, 64L, 69L, 74L, 77L, 82L, 85L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 26L, 28L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 
47L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 68L, 70L, 73L, 
75L, 76L, 84L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 91L, 94L, 98L, 100L, 5L, 59L, 66L, 
67L, 78L, 86L, 92L, 99L, 81L), sim = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("simulation 1", 
"simulation 2", "simulation 3"), class = "factor"), time = c(0, 
100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 
600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 700, 700, 700, 0, 100, 100, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 700, 700, 
700, 800, 800, 900, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 700
), plotstamp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
ggplot(data_long_sort) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_grid(plotstamp ~ sim) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This is the facet grid plot I have so far.

[image]

What I want to do is plot every point in the data frame in each plot, and then choose a color for the points that fall into the time interval. i.e. if the points are shown above then I want a plot with all the points but a different color for those shown within that time interval. Developing from this, I want to include all points that have fallen into the plots above previously. What the data shows is the time in which the host became infected. So I want to show that at timestamp "x", these points were infected.

Comment: that is certainly the data dump of the year so far! Could you clarify maybe - does the is the simulation of importance, or rather the "plotstamp" - i.e, is the sequence within one of each (if not, why not just omitting *at least* (!) 2/3 of the data). Also, what time frame would you want to be the condition for the color, and shall the same color be maintained or shall they get the same color as the next points in the next steps... all somewhat unclear. The downvote is mine. I'd happily remove it of course if this question should become easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the output I was looking for. A time series, demonstrating the increase in prevalence over time. I replaced the plotstamp variable with prevalence and then created a data frame with a boolean condition to determine which points reached a prevalence threshold. I did this for 5 replicate data frames, facetted by sim number and then used ggarrange to merge them together.

[image]

The code for this was as follows:

```
n<-100
data_long_sort$prev<-1:n*(1/n)
COPY.2<-data.frame(data_long_sort)
COPY.2<-COPY.2%>%mutate(BOO=case_when(prev<=.2~TRUE,
                                      prev>.2~FALSE))

plot.2<-ggplot(COPY.2) +geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=!BOO),show.legend = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~sim)+ theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())

COPY.4<-data.frame(data_long_sort)
COPY.4<-COPY.4%>%mutate(BOO=case_when(prev<=.4~TRUE,
                                      prev>.4~FALSE))

plot.4<-ggplot(COPY.4) +geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=!BOO),show.legend = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~sim)+ theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())


COPY.6<-data.frame(data_long_sort)
COPY.6<-COPY.6%>%mutate(BOO=case_when(prev<=.6~TRUE,
                                      prev>.6~FALSE))

plot.6<-ggplot(COPY.6) +geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=!BOO),show.legend = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~sim)+ theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())


COPY.8<-data.frame(data_long_sort)
COPY.8<-COPY.8%>%mutate(BOO=case_when(prev<=.8~TRUE,
                                      prev>.8~FALSE))

plot.8<-ggplot(COPY.8) +geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=!BOO),show.legend = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~sim)+ theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())


COPY1<-data.frame(data_long_sort)
COPY1<-COPY1%>%mutate(BOO=case_when(prev<=1~TRUE,
                                      prev>1~FALSE))

plot1<-ggplot(COPY1) +geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=!BOO),show.legend = FALSE)+facet_wrap(~sim)+ theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())





pplot<-ggarrange(plot.2,plot.4,plot.6,plot.8,plot1,labels=c(.2,.4,.6,.8,1),nrow=5,font.label=list(size=8))
```